# Manipulate query to return Count = 0 in case of no results

Tags: kql

is there a way to manipulate kql query to return 1 row with value 0 for query with summarize aggregation that returns no results ?
e.g. make `traces | summarize Count()`  return count_= 0  instead of empty row.
(I managed to solve it by join with synthetic table but I want to avoid this approach as it reduces performance)

Answer (score 1):

Is it a version issue, since I am running the below and getting what seems to be the answer

```
let temp_table = datatable(c1:int, c2:string)
[1,"A",2,"B",3,"C",];
temp_table
|take 0
|summarize count()
```

[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're summarizing by.

If you're summarizing by `bin(Timestamp, <internal>)`, then `make-series` will do the same for you (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator)), but will put 0 wherever there's a gap.

If you're summarizing by something else, then you'll need a synthetic table, but that's easy to produce using the `range` operator ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rangeoperator)).